# How to use @ControllerAdvice for ViewController's (registered using ViewControllerRegistry)

Tags: spring-mvc

For having a global `@ModelAttribute`, I am using a `@ControllerAdvice`, like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("globalModelAttribute")
    public String getFacebookScope() {
        return "FACEBOOK_SCOPE";
    }

}
```

Now I am able to access the `globalModelAttribute` in all my JSPs except those which are registered as ViewControllers, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Liked to know how to go about this.

Comment: I´m with the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you cannot use **addViewControllers("/login")** because it bypass the `@ControllerAdvice`.

Fixed by creating a `@RequestMapping` for "/login".

Reference:
http://nixmash.com/java/why-your-controlleradvice-may-not-be-firing/